# from bytes to new type conversion

Tags: php, type-conversion, byte

My value is slightly off could someone have a look at how I'm converting it see if there is anything wrong I'm inputting 64MB to bytes and then converting bytes to KB with FileSizeConvert and I'm not quite sure if it's right could someone please have a look and see if there needs to be any changes for 64mb there should be 64000KB and my ouput is 65536KB.

```
public static function convertToBytes($from){
    $number = substr($from, 0, -2);

    switch(strtoupper(substr($from,-2))){
        case "KB":
            return $number*1024;
        case "MB":
            return $number*pow(1024,2);
        case "GB":
            return $number*pow(1024,3);
        case "TB":
            return $number*pow(1024,4);
        case "PB":
            return $number*pow(1024,5);
        default:
            return $from;
    }
}

public static function FileSizeConvert($bytes, $type)
{

    $types = ['TB', 'GB', 'MB', 'KB', 'B'];     
    $index = array_search($type, array_values($types));

    $bytes = floatval($bytes);
        $arBytes = array(
            0 => array(
                "UNIT" => "TB",
                "VALUE" => pow(1024, 4)
            ),
            1 => array(
                "UNIT" => "GB",
                "VALUE" => pow(1024, 3)
            ),
            2 => array(
                "UNIT" => "MB",
                "VALUE" => pow(1024, 2)
            ),
            3 => array(
                "UNIT" => "KB",
                "VALUE" => 1024
            ),
            4 => array(
                "UNIT" => "B",
                "VALUE" => 1
            ),
        );

    $result = $bytes / $arBytes[$index]["VALUE"];
    $result = str_replace(".", "," , strval(round($result, 2)))." ".$arBytes[$index]["UNIT"];
    return $result;     
}
```

usage:

```
$max_file_size = Helper::convertToBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize') . 'B'); // value is 64MB
$kb = Helper::FileSizeConvert($max_file_size, 'KB'); // ouput 65536 KB
```

Comment: Remember powers of 2. 2^10 = 1024. One MB is 1024 kb

Comment: Are you saying the equation is correct

Comment: I'm saying the output is correct. You said the output should be 64000 but that is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

65536/1024=64. You need to remember to think in powers of 2 not base 10